# Reemplazar el ultimo caracter de una cadena si la longitud de la cadena es 4

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiero cambiar el último carácter de una cadena en un data frame, que cumpla la condición que la longitud de la cadena sea igual a 4, entonces preguntar si termina en "1" entonces reemplazar el "1" por la letra "A", si termina en "2" entonces reemplazar el "2" por la letra "B", si termina en "3" entonces reemplazar el "3" por la letra "C".

El código es el siguiente:

```py
df=pd.read_excel("problema01.xlsx")
df=pd.DataFrame(data=df)
print (df)
df["longitud"] = df["codigo"].map(lambda x: len(x))
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df["longitud"].iloc[i] == 4:
        df["Nuevo_codigo"]=np.where(df.codigo.str.endswith('1'),df.codigo.str[:-1]+'A',df.codigo)
        df["Nuevo_codigo"]=np.where(df.codigo.str.endswith('2'),df.codigo.str[:-1]+'B',df.codigo)
        df["Nuevo_codigo"]=np.where(df.codigo.str.endswith('3'),df.codigo.str[:-1]+'C',df.codigo)
        print (df)
```

Tengo 2 problemas: El primer problema es que en un dataframe de 20.000 filas, se demora más de 15 min en realizar el cambio, esto por utilizar "For" e "if".
El segundo problema es que solo realiza el reemplazo en unos valores y en otros no.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Este es el dataframe:

```
+---+------+--------+
|   | item | codigo |
+---+------+--------+
| 0 |    1 | a10    |
| 1 |    2 | a22    |
| 2 |    3 | b101   |
| 3 |    4 | c302   |
| 4 |    5 | f30    |
| 5 |    6 | g453   |
+---+------+--------+
```

y esta es la solución que he encontrado:

```
+---+------+--------+----------+--------------+
|   | item | codigo | longitud | Nuevo_codigo |
+---+------+--------+----------+--------------+
| 0 |    1 | a10    |        3 | a10          |
| 1 |    2 | a22    |        3 | a22          |
| 2 |    3 | b101   |        4 | b101         |
| 3 |    4 | c302   |        4 | c302         |
| 4 |    5 | f30    |        3 | f30          |
| 5 |    6 | g453   |        4 | g45C         |
+---+------+--------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modificar cadenas no es una operación eficiente, son objetos inmutables por lo que hay que crear otro objeto cada vez que quieras modificar algo. Por otro lado dadas las condiciones requeridas realizar una operación vectorizada sin recurrir a código Python estándar es complicado... No obstante algo así debe llevar milisegundos no 15 minutos.

No obstante, solo tienes que iterar una vez y no necesitas generar filtros boleanos con `numpy.where` (en tu caso creas 4 con 20000 elementos cada uno), `map` ya itera sobre la columna implícitamente.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"item": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] * 33334,
                  "codigo": ["a10", "a22", "b101", "c302", "f30", "g453"] * 33334}
                  )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    item codigo
> 0     1    a10
> 1     2    a22
> 2     3   b101
> 3     4   c302
> 4     5    f30
> 5     6   g453
> ```

```
rep_dict = dict(zip("123456789", "ABCDEFGHI"))

df['codigo_n'] = df["codigo"].map(
    lambda cad: (f"{cad[:-1]}{rep_dict.get(cad[-1], cad[-1])}"
        if len(cad) == 4 else cad)
    )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    item codigo codigo_n
> 0     1    a10      a10
> 1     2    a22      a22
> 2     3   b101     b10A
> 3     4   c302     c30B
> 4     5    f30      f30
> 5     6   g453     g45C
> ```

### Explicación

- `rep_dict = dict(zip("123456789", "ABCDEFGHI"))` simplemente crea un diccionario con el carácter a substituir como clave y el carácter que lo substituye como valor.
- `df["codigo"].map(función)` itera sobre cada fila de la columna y llama a la función pasando el valor de cada celda a la misma. El retorno de cada llamada se usa como valor de esa fila para la nueva columna.
- `lambda cad: expresión` es una función lambda equivalente a:

  ```
  def función(cad):
      return expresión
  ```
- `rep_dict.get(cad[-1], cad[-1])` busca el último carácter de la cadena en el diccionario, si lo encuentra retorna el valor, si no lo encuentra retorna el mismo carácter.
- cad[:-1] es un rebanado que retorna toda la cadena menos el último carácter.
- `f"{cadena_1}{cadena_2}"` es un literal de cadena formateado, simplemente concatena la cadena sin el último carácter con el carácter que ha retornado `dict.get`. Podría usarse `+`, pero es  menos eficiente.

### Tiempo de ejecución

En mi caso, para un DataFrame de un millón de filas el tiempo de evaluando solo la generación de la nueva columna (no la carga del Excel) es:

> ```
> %%timeit
> 399 ms ± 22.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
> ```

para uno de 20000 como dices tener:

> ```
> %%timeit
> 8.93 ms ± 851 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal esto? Tal vez funcione con mayor velocidad

```
subst = ['A','B','C'] 
df['codigo-N'] = df["codigo"].map(lambda x: 
    str(x)[:-1]+subst[ord(str(x)[3])-ord('1')] if len(str(x))==4 and str(x)[3] in ['1','2','3'] else x)
```

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!